# Code works in MATLAB 2013 but not in 2017 version (Invalid character code sequence detected)

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use MATLAB as a client for Ebsilon professional software. so i wrote the code below in MATLAB and it works fine in MATLAB 2013. But when i run the same code in MATLAB 2017 it exits with error **"Invalid character code sequence detected."**

I Checked the path and names in Ebsilon software and there is no irregular character. (it works in 2013 version so there should be no problem there)

this is the code:

```
%% Matlab - Ebsilon

app=actxserver('EbsOpen.Application');

% open EBS file
model=app.Open('D:\Ebsilon\Ebs4.ebs');

% get the collection of all objects
objs = model.get('Objects',[],[],[]);
```

the error occurs in `model.get()` part.